# How can I merge an array of objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

Say I had an array of articles, each article may or may not have more than 1 image object, now since mysql can't group together objects, you have to do it yourself. So the result is you getting **near** duplicate article objects...where the only difference is the image object. *By near* duplicate i mean the only difference in the returned result is the image object.

I'm trying to find a way to loop through the `articles` array and elimate duplicate objects and create an `images` array which will hold each `article` image objects.

For example given the below array of articles:

```
{ articles: [
   {article: {articleId: 10, articleText: 'blah'}, image: {articleId: 10,  imageUrl: 'http://differentUrlTooBelow'} },
   {article: {articleId: 10, articleText: 'blah'}, image: {articleId: 10, imageUrl: 'http://AnotherUrlDifferentToAbove'} },
   {article: {articleId: 11, articleText: 'ajsdnfa'}, image: {articleId: 11, imageUrl: 'http://DifferentUrlTooBelow'} },
   {article: {articleId: 11, articleText: 'asfdjnasjdf'}, image: {articleId: 11, imageUrl: 'http://AnotherUrlDifferentToAbove'} },
]}
```

We could use the lodash reduce function, but it seems to only return the last `article (articleId: 11)`...It doesn't seem to find all it's images either. It will just create an images array inside each article. Note that ***res*** is the array of **article** objects (Like shown above)

```
var z = _.reduce(res, function(result, value, key) {
if (key == 0) return;
if(value.article['articleId'] == res[key-1].article['articleId']) {
  result = value;
  result.images = [];
  result.images.push(result.image);
}

return result;
}, {});
```

The end result would look something like this:

```
{ articles: [
   {article: {articleId: 10, articleText: 'blah'}, 
    images: [
       {articleId: 10,  imageUrl: 'http://differentUrlTooBelow'},
       {articleId: 10, imageUrl: 'http://AnotherUrlDifferentToAbove'} 
   ]},
   {article: {articleId: 11, articleText: 'blah'}, 
    images: [
       {articleId: 11,  imageUrl: 'http://differentUrlTooBelow'},
       {articleId: 11, imageUrl: 'http://AnotherUrlDifferentToAbove'} 
   ]},
]}
```

Comment: You probably want to use something along the lines of [`groupBy`](https://lodash.com/docs#groupBy).

Comment: You could exclude the `articleId` in the image object. Seems like redundant data since its already part of the parent `article` object. And if the only data coming from your images is the url than you could just use a [group_concat](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) in your mysql query and then split it later when you need to actually use the urls

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of `_.groupBy()` to match `article.articleId`, then `_.map()` to associate each article using the first item and then set the `images` property by getting all `image` items through `_.map()`.

```js
var data = { 
  articles: [
   {
     article: {articleId: 10, articleText: 'blah'}, 
     image: { articleId: 10, imageUrl: 'http://differentUrlTooBelow' } 
   },
   {
     article: {articleId: 10, articleText: 'blah'}, 
     image: { articleId: 10, imageUrl: 'http://AnotherUrlDifferentToAbove' } 
   },
   {
     article: {articleId: 11, articleText: 'ajsdnfa'}, 
     image: { articleId: 11, imageUrl: 'http://DifferentUrlTooBelow' }
   },
   {
     article: {articleId: 11, articleText: 'asfdjnasjdf'}, 
     image: { articleId: 11, imageUrl: 'http://AnotherUrlDifferentToAbove' } 
   }
  ]
};

var result = {
  articles: _(data.articles)
    .groupBy('article.articleId')
    .map(function(items) {
      return _(items[0])
        .omit('image')
        .set('images', _.map(items, 'image'))
        .value();
    })
    .value()
};

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(result, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.11.2/lodash.js"></script>
```

Comment: Ah nice. I've not used lodash at all really! It's pretty darn powerful :)

Comment: Note if you're doing this server side with node, `_(data.articles)` would be `_.chain(data.articles)` & `_(items[0])` would also need `_.chain(items[0])`.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that it works without using `_.chain()` in nodejs. `_.chain()` is only used when you really don't want some methods to resolve without `.value()` such as using `_.head()` or `_.last()`

Comment: If you notice in the `_.map()` section I could have used chain to get the first item of the array. `_.chain(items).head().omit(...).set(..).value()`.